# BigQuery subsselect example (count and sum)

Tags: count, sum, google-bigquery

In google BigQuery I have done a simple query to get how many music someone has listened.
What I need is to make a sum for all rows returned from the query below (some type of subquery)?

```
select count(1) cnt
from OF7.PETERV_TEST
where gender='F'
group by userId

Row f0_  
1   14   
2   1    
3   7    
4   18   
5   1    
6   4    
7   2    
8   2
```

expected result:

```
49
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
SELECT sum(cnt)
FROM
  (SELECT count(1) cnt
   FROM OF7.PETERV_TEST
   WHERE gender='F'
   GROUP BY userId )
```